# await HttpClient.GetAsync

Tags: .net

```
using System.Net.Http;

var http = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage resp = await http.GetAsync("http://ya.ru");
```

> Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async

ЧЯДНТ? Студия 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод, в котором Вы используете этот код, должен быть помечен модификатором async:

```
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Do();
        }

        public static async void Do()
        {
            var http = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await http.GetAsync("http://ya.ru");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ах вон что оно имело в виду под методом. А я чего-то подумал, что GetAsync должен быть с пометкой.